# quotient of the derivative of two functions by the same argument

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Assume that $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ are two functions in $t$. When is the following true?

$$  \frac{\partial r}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}\right)^{-1}  = \frac{\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}}{\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial s} $$

Would you have a reference? Please let me know if the question has already been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ r=r(t)$  and $ s=s(t)$ are  functions  then according to the chain rule we have  $$ \frac {dr}{ds} =\frac {\frac {dr}{dt}}{ \frac {ds}{dt}}$$

For example if $r=t^2$ and $s=\cos t$ then $$ \frac {dr}{ds} =\frac {\frac {dr}{dt}}{ \frac{ds}{dt}}=\frac {2t}{ -\sin t}$$